# Conditional statement for Excel VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I need a little help.  Let's start with the code:

```
Range("a1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="W1793-PAS (Agency)"
'exclude 1st row (titles)
With Intersect(Range("a1").CurrentRegion, _
               Range("2:60000")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    .Rows.Delete
End With
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
```

I need to create a conditional statement for the above code that will stop the procedure if there is no text matching Criteria1 (W1793-PAS (Agency)).  I don't want this to run if there is no rows with W1793-PAS (Agency) in it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply check if the `Autofilter` is returning anything or not by storing the 
 filtered range in a `Range` object and then delete it

```
Dim rng As Range

'Remove any filters
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

With Range("A1")
  .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="W1793-PAS (Agency)"
  '~~> Set this here
  Set rng = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
End With

'Remove any filters
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

'~~> Check if there were any filtered results and then delete
If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.Delete
```